# Problems with contraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm having some issues trying to design a layout for a fragment in my Android app.
I've placed my UI controls into the design view and added contstraints but when I run my application, each control sits at the bottom of the screen on top of each other.

Please can someone take a look at my xml design code and tell me where I am going wrong.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**fragment_home.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnGo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDOB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:text="DOB"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etRole"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Role"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etDOB"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etDOB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddToDatabase"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Add to database"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/etRole"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etRole"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etRole"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etIntA"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etIntA" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etIntB"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="="
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etIntB" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="result"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Go"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/etIntB"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etIntA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**acticity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What device are you testing this? because on pixel all worked fine

Comment: Pixel 2 API 27 virtual device.

Comment: All works for me on pixel API 24, I am testing this as activity and not fragment, what is you fragment size?

Comment: Ah could it be my fragment container? I'll post my activity_main.xml code.

Comment: @PaulAlexander please check my answer it might help you resolve your issue.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I seem to have fixed it by stretching the fragment container in Design view in activity_main.xml. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code mentioned below. Actually there were few things in your xml that might have messed up your layout specially the `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"` and `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"`. I have removed them and also added few more constraints to balance things out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".HomeFragment">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnGo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etDOB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:text="DOB"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etRole"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Role"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etDOB"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etDOB" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddToDatabase"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add to database"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/etRole"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etRole"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etRole" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etIntA"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etIntA"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etIntA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etIntB"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etIntA" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etIntB"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etIntB" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="result"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etIntB" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Go"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/etIntB"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etIntA"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etIntA" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```